# Redirecionamento em excesso ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Estou com um problema no projeto, quando acesso a rota default, me retorna o seguinte erro.

```
Esta página não está funcionando

Redirecionamento em excesso por localhost
Tente limpar os cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

O erro acontece quando no meu index, eu redireciono para outra `view` de outro `controller`, se eu der `return View()` tudo funciona.

```
namespace Portal.Web.Client.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("")]
    [Route("{action=index}")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("")]
        [Route("index")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //algumas coisas

            if(condicao)
                return RedirectToAction("sign-in","user"); // fica "chamando" este método (Action) infinita vezes.
            else
                return View(); //tudo funciona
        }
    }
}
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de por que isto está ocorrendo, e como resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de ler esta [questão do SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6477253), alterei o

```
return RedirectToAction("sign-in","user");
```

para

```
 return Redirect("~/user/sign-in");
```

e funcionou.